# VueJs, Template, v-bind, embeded html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use the template property within a vue object to place the embedded Html assigned to that property. I currently don't see anything when I bring up the web page. I need to accomplish this task using v-bind in the template property Sample code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Template and v-bind</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Div to Mount App -->
    
    <div id="app"></div>
    

    <!-- Reference to Vue.js library -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    


    <!-- Script Element for our App -->
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                myName: 'Cool Name'
            },
            template: `
                <div>
                    <div v-bind:name="myName"></div> 
                </div>`
                
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove `<template>` wrapper from `<div id="app"></div>` and try.

Comment: @Siddharajsinh Zala   good catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running a test, and came back to see the added comment about removing the `<template>` tag, which I agree with.

However, you also have a problem in that you are trying to bind `myName` to a `<div>` tag `name` attribute, which doesn't exist.  Use handle bars instead.

Here is the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Template and v-bind</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Div to Mount App -->
  <div id="app"></div>

  <!-- Reference to Vue.js library -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

  <!-- Script Element for our App -->
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        myName: 'Cool Name'
      },
      template: `
                <div>
                    <div>{{ myName }}</div> 
                </div>`

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried your approach and that works ; however, is there a way to accomplish the same thing using v-bind. I need that approach for a class.  I tried to mark your answer as a solution but I don't have the reputation points.  Thank you.

Comment: In order to be able to use v-bind, the HTML element needs to have a ```value``` attribute.  Here is a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp).  I did some additional testing to confirm this.  You could possibly ```v-bind:value``` for a disabled ```<input>``` just to output the value.  And you should be able to accept my answer since you posted the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.  Make sure you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can render property value as html content but **it will be rendered literally at html content not effected by VueJS**
So in the following code

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Template and v-bind</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Div to Mount App -->   
        <div id="app" v-html="htmlCont">{{ htmlCont }}</div>
        <!-- Reference to Vue.js library -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <!-- Script Element for our App -->
        <script>
            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    myName: 'Cool Name',
                    htmlCont: `
                    <div>
                        <div>{{ myName }}</div> 
                    </div>`
                },   
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I successfully placed this html inside

```
<div>
    <div>{{ myName }}</div> 
</div>
```

But (myName) variable will not be rendered  by VueJS
So you have to use Vue Component instead as follow

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Template and v-bind</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Div to Mount App -->   
        <div id="app"><html-cont></html-cont></div>
        <!-- Reference to Vue.js library -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <!-- Script Element for our App -->
        <script>
            data_obj = {
                myName: 'Cool Name'
            }
            Vue.component('html-cont',{
                data: function() { return data_obj},
                template: `
                    <div>
                        <div>{{ myName }}</div> 
                    </div>`
                }
            );
            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: data_obj
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer works very well. I appreciate the help.